# Get a folder's changelist

Tags: perforce

If I select from Perforce a folder from my workspace->right-click->Folder History, in the new view that appears, there is a label: `Changhelist: 1234`. Is there a command line that can retrieve this information(e.g. `p4 changelist d:/my_path`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's `p4 changes`. See: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_changes.html

So: `p4 changes -m 1 d:/my_path/...` will show you the most recent changelist that affected files in `d:/my_path/`.

`p4 changelists` is the same as `p4 changes`, so you were very close with your guess, but there is no `p4 changelist`, just `p4 changelists` and `p4 changes`.

Try `p4 help` to see all the available commands.